# Is remiss and negligent interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

I saw that both are adjectives.

Is the only difference between remiss and negligent is that remiss is more 'stylish' and negligent more 'common'?

These are the same right?

> I would be negligent if I don't mention it to you.
>
> I would be remiss if I don't mention it to you.

But are these OK?

> `That's so negligent of you not to mention it to me!
>
> That's so remiss of you not to mention it to me!

Answer (score 2):

Like many words in English, "negligent" and "remiss" have overlapping fields of meaning, but "negligent" can mean "so wrong as to be worthy of legal sanction, usually monetary but even incarceration in the case of criminal negligence," which is not the meaning of "remiss," which is usually used to describe what is impolite or inconsiderate. I have never heard of anyone being taken to court for being remiss.